# Error in converting XPT file to CSV using xport module in spyder (python), but no error in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, spyder

I was able to convert an XPT file to CSV through the anaconda command prompt by installing the xport library and then typing something like this:

`python -m xport file.xpt > file.csv`

However, when I try to convert the file in spyder using the code in the top answer to the post [XPT to CSV Conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716999/xpt-to-csv-conversion), I keep getting the error message "'str' object has no attribute 'read'". My code is as follows:

```
import xport, csv
with xport.XportReader(r'file.xpt') as reader:
    with open(r'file.csv', 'rb') as out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out, [f['name'] for f in reader.fields])
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I've tried to debug this by adding a break statement to the bottom of the for loop to see if it could at least print the first line of the file, but it didn't work. I also tried getting rid of the for loop entirely and instead manually printing the first line, which didn't help either. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved your problem:

- downloaded a sample .xpt file (it would have been good if you had provided a sample) from this thread: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/XPT-file-example-in-v8-format/td-p/628364
- put your code in a script and ran it, with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\Python\sandbox_310\junk.py", line 3, in <module>
    with xport.XportReader(r'class.xpt') as reader:
  File "C:\dev\env\sandbox_310\lib\site-packages\xport\__init__.py", line 839, in __init__
    self.dataset = to_dataframe(fp)
  File "C:\dev\env\sandbox_310\lib\site-packages\xport\__init__.py", line 818, in to_dataframe
    library = load(fp)
  File "C:\dev\env\sandbox_310\lib\site-packages\xport\v56.py", line 954, in load
    bytestring = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

- (again, please provide full tracebacks when asking questions about errors, it saves a lot of busywork)
- Note that the error starts with this line in your code:

```
with xport.XportReader(r'file.xpt') as reader:
```

- (the file I grabbed happened to be called `class.xpt`, so I'm working with that)
- Since it never gets beyond that, I set a breakpoint on that line, and run up to it, then "stepped into" it with my debugger. The code it steps into:

```
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.dataset = to_dataframe(fp)
```

- That's your problem right there, it appears the code expects a file pointer, not a file name. So the fix is easy now:

```
import xport, csv

with open(r'class.xpt', 'rb') as xpt_file:
    with xport.XportReader(xpt_file) as reader:
        with open(r'class.csv', 'wb') as out:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(out, [f['name'] for f in reader.fields])
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

- However, a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\Python\sandbox_310\junk.py", line 4, in <module>
    with xport.XportReader(xpt_file) as reader:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

- You're using `XportReader` in a context manager, but it doesn't support it. So:

```
import xport, csv

with open(r'class.xpt', 'rb') as xpt_file:
    reader = xport.XportReader(xpt_file)
    with open(r'class.csv', 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out, [f['name'] for f in reader.fields])
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

- More errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\Python\sandbox_310\junk.py", line 6, in <module>
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, [f['name'] for f in reader.fields])
  File "F:\Project\Python\sandbox_310\junk.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, [f['name'] for f in reader.fields])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

- `.fields` is a tuple of strings, so you can't access the names with `['name']` - they *are* the names:

```
import xport, csv

with open(r'class.xpt', 'rb') as xpt_file:
    reader = xport.XportReader(xpt_file)
    with open(r'class.csv', 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fields)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

- (note that I simplified `[name for name in reader.fields]` to `reader.fields`, as it'll take any iterable)
- More errors still:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Project\Python\sandbox_310\junk.py", line 8, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python310\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python310\lib\csv.py", line 147, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'Observation' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

- The reader isn't giving you dictionaries at all, but named tuples. So:

```
import xport, csv

with open(r'class.xpt', 'rb') as xpt_file:
    reader = xport.XportReader(xpt_file)
    with open(r'class.csv', 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fields)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row._asdict())
```

- That's not great, because it uses the 'hidden' `._asdict()` of a named tuple to get a dictionary instead. However, the dictionary contains strings, not `bytes` and you probably want single line endings, so:

```
import xport, csv

with open(r'class.xpt', 'rb') as xpt_file:
    reader = xport.XportReader(xpt_file)
    with open(r'class.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=reader.fields)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row._asdict())
```

That works as intended, or at least it works without errors.

What you should take away from this: do one thing at a time and make sure it works as you expect instead of just writing a bunch of lines of code you don't fully understand and hitting "Run" in hopes of a miracle. There were errors on most of the lines you shared, including the very first one, and you clearly didn't look at how the elements you were using were supposed to work.

Start using a debugger and step through your code, and into the external code if you don't understand why a problem occurs. Don't add more code until you're confident the code you wrote so far makes sense.